# DB BROWSER SQLITE3

Tags: database, sqlite

Hi guys i am doing a university project in which we needed to create a database.
I created my tables, triggers and checks and everything works perfectly in DB Browser for sqlite.
The thing is we need to give the files like we made them directly in the Sqlite3 console not the db browser. I can't figure out how do i run this database directly in the sqlite console programm? Which file should i save from the DB Browser? It seems like everything is working perfectly there. Should i rewrite everything in the console?
I would appreciate really any help.

Comment: As a quickstart, you might find the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115838/can-i-run-an-sqlite-operation-from-terminal) helpful. See full documentation for SQLite3 console [here](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#:~:text=Start%20the%20sqlite3%20program%20by,name%20will%20be%20created%20automatically). In short, you should just be able to do `sqlite3 your_db_file.db`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Unix-like operating system, and that your database is called `database.sqlite3` you can dump everything to sql with:

```sh
sqlite3 path/to/database.sqlite3 .dump > database.sql
```